# Does the \newcommand command come with a built in way to set multiple default parameters?

Tags: macros

Using LaTeX. Trying to get a handle on how the `\newcommand` command works. Is it possible to set default values for more than just the first parameter with the builtin syntax? I'm having trouble finding any examples setting more than 1.

Well, I found [an example using a map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176011/newcommand-multiple-default-values), but I'm really just trying to learn the language. Don't need to go crazy just yet.

Comment: No, `\newcommand` can only define commands with one optional argument (referred to as `#1` in the body of the definition).

Comment: @egreg, thanks that's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You really want to use `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of `\newcommand` but, if you’re thinking in terms of default parameters, then you should look at the `keyval` package instead. A lot depends on what precisely you’re attempting to do.

Comment: I heard that this is now part of LaTeX core.  Is it documented anywhere other than xparse?

Comment: It might be in the *LaTeX Companion* (2nd edition), it should definitely be in the 3rd edition due out next year. My chapter on defining new commands in my book only documents `\NewDocumentCommand`, but right now texdoc xparse is the easiest source of documentation.

But yes, it's been in LaTeX core since the Oct 2020 release.

Comment: My blog post at https://www.preppylion.com/weird-xparse-tricks/ talks about one way of being able to have multiple optional arguments without having to specify each optional argument.

Comment: @DonHosek Thanks, Idk what xparse support is like on overleaf, but I'll give ``\NewDocumentCommand` a try.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Overleaf doesn't have the current LaTeX version, and if it doesn't it will definitely have the `xparse` package available.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was about learning how `\newcommand` works with regard to optional arguments, the answer is that `\newcommand` constructs can indirectly digest more than one optional argument, but in a non-expandable way.  The technique involves calling on a second helper macro to absorb the second optional argument.

Note also that the second optional argument cannot be defined without also defining a first optional argument.

Here, `\first` is the user macro, taking two optional and one mandatory arguments.  It uses the helper-macro `\Second` to absorb the second optional argument (and the mandatory argument).  Note also that `\firstarg` must be expanded once if it is needed to recover the actual tokens of the first optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\first[1][optA]{\def\firstarg{#1}\Second}
\newcommand\Second[2][optB]{The arguments are \firstarg, #1, and #2}
\begin{document}
\first{X}

\first[Z]{X}

\first[Z][Y]{X}
\end{document}
```

[image]